# Parse namespaced xml with ruby nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xml, parsing, nokogiri

I have as second of xml

```
<Environment
  Name="test"
  xmlns="http://schemas.dmtf.org/ovf/environment/1"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:oe="http://schemas.dmtf.org/ovf/environment/1"
  oe:id="123456789">
  <PropertySection>
      <Property oe:key="mykey" oe:value="test"/>
  </PropertySection>
</Environment>
```

I'm using ruby and nokogiri to parse the document. i.e.

```
file = File.open('/tmp/myxml.xml')
doc = Nokogiri::XML(file)

env = doc.at('Environment')
id = env['id']  
printf("ID [%s]\n", id)
properties = env.at('PropertySection')
```

This works and successfully prints the id from the xml.
I now want to access the Property attribute with the key 'mykey'.  I tried the following:

```
value = properties.at('Property[@key="mykey"]')['value']
printf("Value %s\n", value)
```

Unfortunately the properties.at method returns a nil object.  I tried modifying the xml itself to remove the 'oe' namespace from the attribute 'key'.  Re-running my script it works.

How can I get nokogiri to recognise the namespace when calling .at() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the Nokogiri namespace syntax: http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html#namespaces.

First, make sure you have namespaces you can use:

```
ns = {
  'xmlns' => 'http://schemas.dmtf.org/ovf/environment/1',
  'oe' => 'http://schemas.dmtf.org/ovf/environment/1'
}
```

(I'm defining both even though they are the same in this example). You might also look into using the namespaces already available in `doc.collect_namespaces`.

Then you can just do:

```
value = properties.at('./xmlns:Property[@oe:key="mykey"]/@oe:value', ns).content
```

Note that I am using `./` here because, for this specific search, Nokogiri interprets the XPath as CSS without it. You may wish to use `.//`.

Comment: Thanks,  that worked.  I had tried '@oe:key="mykey" which didn't work, but specifying the namespace for the otter tag and other attribute worked.