# ruby substring backslash plus "

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So, I have a string like this:

```
str1 = "blablablabla... original_url=\"https://facebook.com/125642\"> ... blablablabla..."
```

what is the best approach to extract this original_url?

what I have done so far is this:

```
original_url = str1['content'][str1['content'].index('original_url')+12..str1['content'].index('>')-2]
```

it works, but it seems such like a poor solution, mostly I'm stuggling to find this substring `/">`

here's what I have tried so far

```
str1.index('\">')
str1.index('\\">') # escaping only one backslach
str1.index('\\\">') # escaping both back slash and "
str1.index("\\\">") # was just without idea over here
```

I'm not a ruby programmer, so I'm kinda lost here

Comment: Where is the string originally coming from? Is it some sort of structured format (JSON, HTML, CSV)?

Comment: it's a xmlns format

Comment: Then I would suggest using Nokogiri like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18087623/2483313

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/544825

Answer (score 0):

The best approach to parse xml namespaces is to use Nokogiri as suggested by @spickermann.

Quick but not elegant and not even efficient solutions:

```
str1 = "blablablabla... original_url=\"https://facebook.com/125642\"> ... blablablabla..."

original_url=str1[str1.index("original_url")+14...str1.index("\">")] 
# => "https://facebook.com/125642" 

original_url=str1.split(/original_url=\"/)[1].split(/">/).first
# => "https://facebook.com/125642"
```